# Long slots in gnd plane of 2 layer board

Tags: pcb-design, ground-plane, copper-pour

I'm trying to design a computer keyboard pcb (2 layer), and because of the placement constraints intrinsic to this situation, I have very long (spanning 80% of the dimension) slots (discontinuities) in my ground planes/copper pours (same problem in both layers, in perpendicular axes).

Here is a crude visualisation of the problem (orange is parts where both F and B Cu layers are present):
[image: crappy picture trying to depict the problem]

In terms of AC signals, I'm using some neopixel LEDs (<1MHz) for the key backlights, and I have a DC-DC converter in one corner of the board (~1.2Mhz). I'm also using USB FS (12MHz), but that too is limited to just a 2cm wide strip one one side of the board.

Is via stitching the right approach here? Or is it advisable here to not have ground fills? I'm limited to 2 layers by cost.

I see via stitching suggested when, for example, the ground plane is split into two, but in my case, it's split into 4 horizontal sections and 6 vertical sections => too many vias?

Also, is there a rule of thumb for via spacing that I should be aware of?